# trying to execute r web scraping code but giving an error

Tags: r

I am trying to execute the below code and getting the error when the joblocations execution.The pages are loaded into the ulrs but the locations are not extracted from web page.

```
library(data.table)
library(XML)
pages<-c(1:12)

ulrs <- rbindlist(lapply(pages, function(x)
    {url <- paste("http://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/",x,"/",sep = " ")
    data.frame(url)}),fill = TRUE)


joblocations <- rbindlist(apply(ulrs,1,function(url){
    doc1 <- htmlParse(url)
    locations <- getNodeSet(doc1,'//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span/text()')
data.frame(sapply(locations,function(x){xmlValue(x)}))    
} ),fill = TRUE)


Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/%201%20/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, changing the `http` to `https` will get you past that error with `XML` but then leads to another: `WARNING: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/1/` and still doesn't work.

I tried again, swapping out use of the `XML` package for `rvest` and got it working.

```
library(data.table)
library(rvest)

pages<-c(1:12)

ulrs <- rbindlist(lapply(pages, function(x)
{url <- paste0("http://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/",x,"/")
data.frame(url)}
),fill = TRUE)

joblocations <- rbindlist(apply(ulrs,1,function(url){
  doc1 <- read_html(url)
  locations <- html_nodes(doc1,xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span/text()')
  data.frame(sapply(locations,function(x){html_text(x)}))    
} ))
```

`rvest` seems to work whether http or https is specified, but that is something that has tripped me up before.

Comment: hello Jul...still getting this error 
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

Comment: Just edited the answer. The issue there is with the `sep` parameter of the `paste` command. `sep=""` should work, but when building urls for web scraping, it's probably best to use `paste0` instead.